# how to import php script that convert mysql data to json format, from d3.json function in force directed layout

Tags: php, mysql, json, d3.js, force-layout

I am using d3 tool for visualization. I have converted my mysql data into json format which is expected as an input to d3.

And now, I am phasing a problem in calling that php script from d3 code. At present I am calling like this:

```
    d3.json("getdata.php", function(json) {
    force
      .nodes(json.nodes)
      .links(json.links)
      .start();
```

and it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple answer, so I expect that you may have already covered it, but if you are using d3.v3.js, you may need to include an error reference in your JSON call like this;

```
d3.json("getdata.php", function(error, json) {
    force 
        .nodes(json.nodes)
        .links(json.links)
        .start();
```

Might I be so bold to check out the following post to see if it helps;
http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html

Failing that, If you can post more of your code and data that will help others troubleshoot.

Good luck :-)

Comment: thnx a lot... but i m getting a type error: json is unidentified on console. please help how to correct it.

Comment: sory its json is undefined.

Comment: Good work! If you have the time and if the solution is something that may help others in the future. Editing your original post to let future readers know would be cool :-)